# Aggregation without using subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table drinks:

| person_id | type | drunk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COKE | true |
| 1 | FANTA | false |
| 2 | TIMER | false |
| 2 | COKE | true |
| 2 | PEPSI | false |
| 2 | PEPSI | false |
| 3 | TIMER | false |
| 3 | FANTA | false |
| 3 | COKE | true |
| 3 | COKE | true |
| 3 | PEPSI | true |
| 4 | TIMER | false |
| 4 | COKE | true |

Goal:

| person_id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | TIMER |
| 4 | TIMER |

There is a table with the drinks of persons. A person can have multiple types of multiple drinks which can be drunk. Some persons do have a TIMER which tolds them when to drink.
My goal is to create a query - without a subquery - thats lists me all persons timers, who drunk all dark drinks the person posses.

Explanation:

- Person 1 has no TIMER -> irrelevant
- Person 2 has a TIMER, but has two undrunken PEPSI -> irrelevant
- Person 3 has a TIMER, has drunk his COKE's & PEPSI (FANTA is not important here) -> yes please
- Person 4 has a TIMER, has only a drunken COKE -> yes please

I've already a solution for this, but I want it without a Subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM drinks d LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT person_id,
               array_agg(type) AS agg_types,
               array_agg(drunk) AS agg_drunk
        FROM drinks 
        WHERE type::TEXT = ANY(ARRAY['COKE', 'PEPSI'])
        GROUP BY person_id
        ) AS sub ON d.person_id = sub.person_id
WHERE d.type = 'TIMER'
  AND TRUE = ALL(sub.agg_drunk)
  AND FALSE = d.drunk
```

I look forward to any help, thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select person_id, 'TIMER'
from drinks d
group by person_id
having count(*) filter (where d.type = 'TIMER') > 0 and
       count(*) filter (where d.type in ('Coke', 'Pepsi') and drunk) = 2;
```

Note:  In your example data there are no duplicates.  If that is possible, then the second condition would use `count(distinct)`:

```
       count(distinct d.type) filter (where d.type in ('Coke', 'Pepsi') and drunk) = 2;
```

Comment: Wow thank you! And yes duplicates are possible, I've just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a anti-join to find who hasn't drank their dark drinks.

For example:

```
select d.person_id, d.type
from drinks d
left join (
  select person_id
  from drinks
  where type in ('COKE', 'PEPSI') and drunk = 'false'
) u on u.person_id = d.person_id
where d.type = 'TIMER'
  and u.person_id is null
```